# How does SNES RAM memory address vs ROM address play a part in creating an emulator?

Tags: assembly, emulation, memory-address, machine-code, nintendo

If you are making an emulator, does the ROM's machine code reference it's own addresses? Does it refer to locations that it gets mapped to in SNES memory?

When manuals are talking about Direct Paging, absolute, long, etc addressing modes -- they are referring to the SNES's WRAM memory, is this correct?

So when interpreting the machine code of a ROM, do you have to convert to SNES memory locations?

Answer (score 0):

> If you are making an emulator, does the ROM's machine code reference it's own addresses?

There's no such limitation. Code executing from ROM can access RAM, and vice versa.

> When manuals are talking about Direct Paging, absolute, long, etc addressing modes -- they are referring to the SNES's WRAM memory, is this correct?

The CPU's addressing modes always apply; they've got nothing to do with RAM or ROM.

> So when interpreting the machine code of a ROM, do you have to convert to SNES memory locations?

Not sure what you mean by "SNES memory locations", but you have to take [the memory mapping](http://wiki.superfamicom.org/snes/show/Memory+Mapping) into account.

Comment: But how does the code in the ROM specify whether it is talking about an address in the SNES WRAM or the ROM. I feel like I am missing a crucial part in understanding how this all works.

Comment: As they show on the page I linked to, WRAM is mapped into certain banks. Typically you'd use banks $7E and $7F (i.e. addresses $7E0000-$7FFFFF) to access WRAM, since that gives you a contiguous 128kB block of RAM.

Comment: I'm sorry, I must not be explaining myself very clearly. I'm going to try to put it into a concrete example. Let's say the bytes I am interpreting in the ROM come out to something like LDA $230001 (random number I picked). When the ROM is loaded into the SNES, this bank on the ROM is mapped to a different address in the SNES, right? So is the address $230001 talking about an address on the ROM image or is it talking about an address that the ROM was mapped to in the SNES? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Address $230001 would access WRAM (this is also shown on the page I linked to). For a HiROM game you'd use the mirror starting at $C00000, i.e. address $E30001 in your case. For a LoROM game you don't have ROM in the lower halves of each bank; only the upper half ($8000-$FFFF) of the relevant banks contains ROM. A simpler example would be if you accessed address $18000. This would correspond to offset $18000 in a HiROM game, and to offset $8000 in a LoROM game.

Comment: If I understand correctly (I've never worked with the 65816) isn't it possible for a zero page access to represent different memory depending on what the DP register is set to? So you might see `LDA $00` in the code but this isn't necessarily address `$000000`?